# Different schema for different entites

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities in my spring boot project

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE1", schema="Sch1")
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE2", schema="Sch2")
```

I want both these schemas to be configurable in `application.properties`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: what do you mean ?Do you want these tables to be dynamically when you run the project?Are you asking what you should write in the application.properties file for this?

Comment: @YusufBEŞTAŞ I dont want it to be based on every request, else I would go for multitenancy approach. I just want it to be configurable before the application starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done.

In Java, an annotation attribute value must be a constant expression because it is resolved at compile time. Hence, having this configured dynamically based on `application.properties` is not possible.

---

Assuming that having these values configured in a common and single place is ok and enough for your use case you could do the following:

```java
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
    static final String TABLE1_SCHEMA = "Sch1";
    static final String TABLE2_SCHEMA = "Sch2";

    // (...)
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE1", schema = DatabaseConfiguration.TABLE1_SCHEMA)
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE2", schema = DatabaseConfiguration.TABLE2_SCHEMA)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What could be the next best approach if not using application.properties?

Comment: If what you want is to keep the values configured in a common and single place, you could create a constant (static final attribute) in a related file (let us say a `DatabaseConfiguration` class). I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No you can, but what you can try to do, is to define the entity metadata in the xml file: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/xml-overriding.html

Then you can combine this xml file and maven resource filtering:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Or if you use gradle, then you should call processResources gradle task.

To define this schema info at build time.